# My vector perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTeX

Tags: pdf, includegraphics

I have a pdf picture with drawn 1cm wide "pixels" on it, and neat borders between the squares.

However when I import it into Latex with
`\includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{Pictures/image.pdf}`
I get an interpolation of the color squares (and not so much of the titles etc.).

[image]

I tried the option
`\includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth,interpolate=false]{Pictures/imagepdf}`
but it seems the option only applies to raster files.

What can I do to the prevent the interpolation?
I am using pdfLaTex on Overleaf.

Comment: Are you sure that the original picture is *fully* vector? Please post a complete *minimal* example so that we can investigate. One thing you can do is to try to include the picture without scaling (I suspect that the colored part is really a pixmap embedded in the PDF).

Comment: I think you are right, I didn't know about embedded pixmap. I opened the pdf as .txt and found this object: `<</Subtype/Image
/Mask[0
0]
/ColorSpace 13 0 R
/Width 9
/Height 10
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 91>>stream
....
endstream
endobj` which seems to code a bitmap.

Comment: If you created this image with Matlab/Python/etc. you could probably get the heat map as a vector graphic as well. Or you trace it in Inkscape if this really bothers you.